# Making a scrolling floor like in Street fighter 2 in XNA(Monogame)

Tags: xna, monogame

How would I make a scrolling pseudo 3d floor like in street fighter 2 in XNA(or more specifically MonoGame)?

https://gyazo.com/ea78954a5d96c3cb522eeac4a6ee5f21

for reference, if you aren't aware what I'm talking about. I Understand the concept of how it was done on the SNES(moving each line of the sprite separately) but how could I achieve the same effect in XNA with today's technology and libraries?

Comment: You would do it with actual 3D since it’s much easier

Comment: But wouldn't that be a bit heavy for a 2d game optimization wise? and wouldn't that be a lot of effort for such a seemingly simple effect?

Comment: No, it wouldn’t. It would be very little effort to tilt two triangles to make it happen and all 2D is basically rendered through the same system that 3D is done anyway. So it would be much more effort to start playing with shaders or CPU based rendering

Comment: alright, however i'm trying to recreate the floor part of sf2 as best as i can using one of the sprites from the game, which is this(https://gyazo.com/32edc3f7bc3d2f4b8c47e7a1ca8474fe). In theory i could manipulate it to be a flat texture, but it would end up look weirdly stretched and different from the original in game, So unfortunately in my specific situation it seems i'm kinda stuck with the 2d solution :p. Would there maybe be a way to make a flat quad and just make it look 2d but allow for vector manipulating which could possibly achieve the effect?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple ViewPort. 
A ViewPort basically shows only a little scene from an overall bigger Picture. Like you have it in sides crollers or RPGs. You only see the current scene and not the complete Level/World.

An implementation example can be found here:
http://community.monogame.net/t/simple-2d-camera/9135

It might be a bit tricky to understand everything at the beginning, but at the end you can reuse this for almost any 2D game and several effects (camera shake, Rotation and so on) so it's worth the effort,

Comment: I think you misunderstood, i've already got a camera setup with matrix and all that, I'm trying to achieve the pseudo 3d floor effect from street fighter 2 where a single sprite was taken and manipulated line by line to look like a scrolling floor(https://gyazo.com/ea78954a5d96c3cb522eeac4a6ee5f21)